Wifi option disappeared after update, 22.04
After I just ran update manager, suddenly my wifi options disappeared. Here is what i've gone through so far:
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:80500000-8050ffff


lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f3:2753 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5365 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:b00a Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Realtek Bluetooth 4.2 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Iris Plus Graphics G1 (Ice Lake) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a03 (rev 03)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 30)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP DRAM Controller (rev 30)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 30)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 30)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Management Engine (rev 30)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 34bf (rev 30)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev 30)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP LPC Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SMBus Controller (rev 30)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Ice Lake-LP SPI Controller (rev 30)
01:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Micron Technology Inc Device 5410 (rev 01)

rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

sudo modprobe rtl8821ce && sudo dmesg | grep 8821
modprobe: FATAL: Module rtl8821ce not found in directory /lib/modules/6.8.0-40-generic

Previously, I had a similar problem, which is detailed in this thread
In that case, it was fixed with cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall. However, that isn't working this time. It gives the error:
cd backport-iwlwifi && sudo make uninstall
Generating local configuration database from kernel ...Kernel version parse failed!
make: *** [Makefile:42: uninstall] Error 1

We've now determined that the wifi works when booted to kernel 6.5 but fails when booted to 6.8. @jeremy31's suggestion gives (in 6.8):
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    DeviceName: Realtek Wireless LAN + BT
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:831a]
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:5410] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Micron Technology Inc Device [1344:0100]


is there anything in this Ubuntu Forums post which helps?

@graham going to the previous kernel (6.5.0-45-generic) fixes the issue and wifi works. I haven't been able to implement the second part which fixes it so the current kernel (6.8.0-40-generic) works on reboot. Any guidance on that part?

Can you get info from kernel 6.8?  lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; dkms status

@Jeremy31 running that command while booted in 6.8 (wifi not working) gives the outputs I just put in the main post. When run in 6.5 the output is the same except the last line about the "subsystem" is not present.

@Jeremy31 if the previous kernel works maybe wait for next kernel update unless there are other compelling reasons to have 6.8.0-40?

In terminal run wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info  Enter your password when asked and press y and enter when asked if you want to upload results, then post URL from terminal here.  I want to see results from 6.8 kernels because 6.5 are no longer supported

@Jeremy31 Here are the pastebin results in 6.8: https://termbin.com/tu3v

You must have blacklisted the kernel module that is used in the 6.8 kernel and that rtl8821ce-dkms doesn't seem to work on that kernel.  In terminal do
sudo sed -i 's/blacklist rtw88_8821ce/#blacklist rtw88_8821ce/' /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
Then reboot into the 6.8 kernel

Thanks, I don't know how I could have done that accidentally, but this worked.
